# Enum Case not found in type

Tags: swift, enums

```
enum Operator: Character {
    case Substract = "-"
    case Add = "+"
    case Multiply = "*"
    case Divide = "/"
}
```

I have enum above and a function declared below which checks if we have valid operator. e.g. **isOperator("+")**

```
func isOperator(_ symbol: Character)-> Operator? {        
        let op = Operator(rawValue: symbol)       
        switch op {
            case .Substract, .Add, .Multiply, .Divide:
                return op
            default:
                return nil
        }
    }
```

What compiler returns here is *"Enum Case not found in type"* means cases defined in my switch statement (.Add .. etc) is not available in Operator type. Why compiler not able to find case since **op** is an operator type which swift inver types atuomatically?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, Because your `let op = Operator(rawValue: symbol)` is `optional` and in `switch` case your are matching exact values. So you can apply `optional` in `case` while comparing. as like below.

```
func isOperator(_ symbol: Character)-> Operator? {
    let op = Operator(rawValue: symbol)
    switch op {
    case .Substract?, .Add?, .Multiply?, .Divide?:
        return op
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have only 4 cases then you can

```
func isOperator(_ symbol: Character)-> Operator? {
    return Operator(rawValue: symbol)
}
```

But if you are going to have more in the future then it's better to use `guard` before`switch`

```
func isOperator(_ symbol: Character)-> Operator? {
    guard let op = Operator(rawValue: symbol) else {
        return nil
    }

    switch op {
        case .Substract, .Add, .Multiply, .Divide:
            return op

        ...

    }
}
```

---

- In the newest version of swift, swift 3, the naming convention of enums has changed. Every enum cases has followed `camelCase` rules.
- When you use function name like **`is`**`Something` then this function should return `Bool`

Comment: Thanks Adrian for naming convention. Even if we are adding multiple cases say power(^) then your 1st version will give me an opertor and if some non-opeator value is passed then enum will not be initialized and will return nil. So I don't see use of guard here. Do you?

Comment: @manismku In my first version there isn't `guarda` because `init (rawValue:)` is optional and if it fails then it returns nila.

Answer (score 2):

It is Swift convention to name your cases starting with a lowercase letter:

```
enum Operator: Character {
    case subtract = "-", add = "+", multiply = "*", divide = "/"
}
```

If you want to check if it is a valid operator you function should return Bool. You could extend Character and create a read only computed property as follow:

```
extension Character {
    var isOperator: Bool {
        return Operator(rawValue: self) != nil
    }
}
```

---

Testing

```
Character("/").isOperator   // true

if let op = Operator(rawValue: "-") {
    print(op) // "subtract\n"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leo. I think I wanted to have name changed in my example since I am looking for an enum as returned value to function. You version is also correct in case where only boolean is required.